Code: -26, Error: non-mandatory-script-verify-flag (Data push larger than necessary)" when trying to spend from P2WSH
I have sent to a P2WSH but I can't spend from this address because I get this error;
Code: -26, Error: non-mandatory-script-verify-flag (Data push larger than necessary)"
This is the script that was hashed to make the P2WSH address:
Raw hex:
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
Script with comments;
93 - op_add
01 - OP_PUSHBYTES_1
08
87 - op_equal
00 - OP_0
63 - OP_IF ?
03 - OP_PUSHBYTES_3
6f7264 - "ord"
01 - OP_PUSHBYTES_1
01
09 - OP_PUSHBYTES_9 ?
696d6167652f706e67 - "image/png"
00 - OP_0
4d0802 - OP_PUSHDATA2, 520 bytes
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
30 - OP_PUSHBYTES48
1bac856563cb78838b82215de7a54233b0f755be164b7f36c46ae50752e785b8f36ef2c30000000049454e44ae426082
68 - OP_ENDIF ?
As you can tell it should be spendable by just pushing two 4s onto the stack in the wittness.
Any help much apprecisted

Please fix the formatting, this is very hard to read

Bitcoin Core standardness rules require data pushes to be minimal, i.e. where multiple ways exist to push the same byte vector, the shortest one must be used. (See explanation at Opcode Explained.)
In two cases you're pushing a single byte with OP_PUSHBYTES_1 that you should push with a dedicated opcode, namely 08 and 01. Use OP_8 (0x58) and OP_1 (0x51) respectively instead.
